# Store a changes in Dataset Using Git

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm trying to store and track the huge and frequently changing structure of Power BI Dataset using Git.

Right now it's a text or .MD formatted document where all Power Query queries (manually copy-pasted one by one) are stored. All measures also are imported using DAX Studio and written at the end.

Briefly it looks like this:

```
* Custom Functions
    * ExtractJsonFileContent
      let
          Source = (fileContent) =>
      let
      Source = Json.Document(fileContent)
      in
      Source
      in
          Source
    * Countries
      let
          Source = Json.Document(DS{[Name="lookups"]}[Content]{[Name="Countries.json"]}[Content],65001),
          #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
---
          #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type",{{"Country", Order.Ascending}}),
          #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "heapCountryId", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
      in
          #"Added Index"    

DEFINE 
---- MODEL MEASURES BEGIN ----

MEASURE 'Some Table'[Fail Rate_Int] = 
    DIVIDE(
        [Total Failed Tickets_Int],
        [Total Created Tickets_Int]
        )
MEASURE 'Some Table'[Success Rate] = 1 - [Fail Rate_Int]
---- MODEL MEASURES END ----
```

Maybe there is a more effective way to store these structures?

And one more question: How to store the relations between tables and measures?

Comment: Power BI Developer mode now enables git integration to track changes, would that help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/

Comment: Yes, the Reports are stored as .PBIP (Projects) - in another Repository. But the question is exactly about dataset - which is continuously changing (sometimes with faults) and with data exceeding more than 1 GB.

Comment: Tracking data is not a good use case, and not good for git, you'll need a database or some method like it to deal with snapshots and update items

Comment: Jon, why are you supposing I'm so stupid to store the data in Git? In the initial post, I'm writing about a **structure** - tables, measures, and relations - and nothing about data. Data is continuously changing on Data Lake and transferring into tables with some rules, which I'm trying to track

Comment: I don't know, maybe because you mentioned  'the question is exactly about dataset - which is continuously changing (sometimes with faults) and with data exceeding more than 1 GB', which is a bit ambiguous, in terms of 'dataset', I read it the wrong way. To be fair, in a few PBI projects that I have consulted on, people do try to track changes in data with git.